# Сортировка List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();

Tags: c#, .net

У меня есть`List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>();` в который я из словаря записываю слово и его вес. Как через метод `Sort();` можно вывести 5 самых "тяжелых" слов и их вес.
Надо перегружать метод или как-то через IComparable?

Comment: А почему не просто Dictionary ?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я знаю, как сделать через Dictionary и OrderBy, но необходимо именно через List

Comment: @Илья, если ты заменишь Dictionary на List, то твой метод _как сделать через Dictionary и OrderBy_ останется рабочим

Comment: @Grundy, мне стало интересно, можно ли обойтись без OrderBy, да и вообще без LINQ

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если нужно именно через метод `Sort`, то таким образом:

```
list.Sort((pair1, pair2) => pair1.Value >= pair2.Value ? -1 : 1);
var heaviestWords = list.Take(5).ToList();
```

Но нагляднее через LINQ:

```
var heaviestWords = list.OrderByDescending(pair => pair.Value).Take(5).ToList();
```